# Create a list of namedtuples from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe like this:

df1

```
Name   Category  Age
Harry   A        11
James   B        23
Will    A        19
```

I want to create a list of tuples using `namedtuple` from `collections`. The list should be like this:

```
output_list = [Variable(Name='Harry', Age=11), Variable(Name='James', Age=23), Variable(Name='Will', Age=19)]
```

This is what I've tried using 'itertuples'

```
output_list = list(df1[["Name","Age"]].itertuples(name='Variable', index=False))
```

Comment: In fact, I don't understand what is your question. The second form is what you want, no? And it's probably better than my answer using `namedtuple`

Comment: So, what *happened* when you tried? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from collections import namedtuple

COLS = ['Name', 'Age']
Variable = namedtuple('Variable', field_names=COLS)
output_list = df[COLS].apply(lambda x: Variable(**x), axis=1).tolist()
print(output_list)

# Output
[Variable(Name='Harry', Age=11),
 Variable(Name='James', Age=23),
 Variable(Name='Will', Age=19)]
```

Comment: He doesn't have the "Category" in his output example :)

Comment: Why is this better than the OP's solution?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Did you read my comment above?

Comment: yes? Again, why is doing this better than `list(df1[["Name","Age"]].itertuples(name='Variable', index=False))`?

Comment: From my comment to the question: *And it's probably better than my answer using namedtuple*

Comment: Oh, you meant in the answer above. Yeah ok, you seemed to have noticed as well.

Comment: Look, it's probably best to ask for clarification from the OP, honestly, the question should be closed because it isn't clear *what is being asked*.

Comment: Maybe you are right but the OP asks *I want to create a list of tuples using namedtuple from collections*. It's what my answer does :-P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for but:

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df1[['Name','Age']].to_numpy()]
tuples
```

Output:

```
[('Harry', 11), ('James', 23), ('Will', 19)]
```

Comment: Why is this better than the OP's stated solution?